# How to modify the album/photo upload process?

Tags: php, facebook-graph-api

I'm creating a `FaceBook` app where the user selects multiple images and the application generates a single image from them (`PHP`).  I'm giving the generated image a `semi-random name - $storage_url = $rack_directory . "rack_" . mt_rand() . mt_rand() . ".png"; (e.g. rack_2128639756968968165.png)` and storing it temporarily as well.

I'd like the user to be able to upload the generated image to their `Facebook` profile directly from the page rather than `downloading` and then `uploading` it.

In looking over answers in this site as well as others it looks like I can use this:

```
   $app_id = "YOUR_APP_ID";
   $app_secret = "YOUR_APP_SECRET";
   $post_login_url = "YOUR_POST-LOGIN_URL";
   $album_name = 'YOUR_ALBUM_NAME';
   $album_description = 'YOUR_ALBUM_DESCRIPTION';

   $code = $_REQUEST["code"];

   //Obtain the access_token with publish_stream permission 
   if(empty($code))
     {
       $dialog_url= "http://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?"
       . "client_id=" . $app_id 
       . "&redirect_uri=" . urlencode($post_login_url)
       . "&scope=publish_stream";
       echo("<script>top.location.href='" . $dialog_url . 
       "'</script>");
   } 
   else {
     $token_url= "https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/"
     . "access_token?"
     . "client_id=" .  $app_id 
     . "&redirect_uri=" . urlencode( $post_login_url)
     . "&client_secret=" . $app_secret
     . "&code=" . $code;
     $response = file_get_contents($token_url);
     $params = null;
     parse_str($response, $params);
     $access_token = $params['access_token'];

     // Create a new album
     $graph_url = "https://graph.facebook.com/me/albums?"
     . "access_token=". $access_token;

     $postdata = http_build_query(
     array(
      'name' => $album_name,
      'message' => $album_description
        )
      );
     $opts = array('http' =>
     array(
      'method'=> 'POST',
      'header'=>
        'Content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
      'content' => $postdata
      )
     );
     $context  = stream_context_create($opts);
     $result = json_decode(file_get_contents($graph_url, false, 
       $context));

     // Get the new album ID
     $album_id = $result->id;

     //Show photo upload form and post to the Graph URL
     $graph_url = "https://graph.facebook.com/". $album_id
       . "/photos?access_token=" . $access_token;
     echo '<html><body>';
     echo '<form enctype="multipart/form-data" action="'
     .$graph_url. ' "method="POST">';
     echo 'Adding photo to album: ' . $album_name .'<br/><br/>';
     echo 'Please choose a photo: ';
     echo '<input name="source" type="file"><br/><br/>';
     echo 'Say something about this photo: ';
     echo '<input name="message" type="text"
        value=""><br/><br/>';
     echo '<input type="submit" value="Upload" /><br/>';
     echo '</form>';
     echo '</body></html>';
  }
```

...to generate a unique album and upload the picture...
But - I don't want to display a form that has a user browse to and upload (after they right/control click and save the image from the page).  Just take the existing generated image displayed on the page and submit that.

Is there a function that I could use so that this process occurs and the only form requirement is to submit and upload?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

What you need is the Facebook SDK :https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/php/

This makes all those "Graph" calls much simpler.

Pasting from that page:

```
// Load the facebook SDK
require_once("facebook.php");

$config = array();
$config['appId'] = 'YOUR_APP_ID';
$config['secret'] = 'YOUR_APP_SECRET';
$config['fileUpload'] = false; // optional

$facebook = new Facebook($config);

try { 
   $uid = $facebook->getUser();
catch (FacebookApiException $e) { 
   // Not logged on - you should log them on. Various methods, but redirect to $facebook->getLoginURL() is simplest. Docs: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/php/facebook-getLoginUrl/
}
```

Once the user is logged on, you can upload also through the SDK:

```
// Now upload the file
try { 
    $facebook->setFileUploadSupport('http://MyDomain.com/'); 
    $response = $facebook->api( 
      '/me/photos/', 
      'post', 
      array( 
        'message' => 'Image Cpation', 
        'source' => '@/path/to/image' // @-sign must be the first character 
      ) 
    ); 
  } 
  catch (FacebookApiException $e) { 
    error_log('Could not post image to Facebook.'); 
  }
```

You cna use an album ID in place of "me" for uploading directly to a specific album. But working your way through the SDK will help a lot more than trying it all manually with the graph calls!

Sorry, It's not a complete "here's the code" answer (there's still a bit of work to go), but that should help you upload without prompting the user.

Comment: Incidentally, you will need the upload photos permission for this, not publish_stream.

Comment: Thanks Robbie for responding so quickly.  I've been playing with your suggestions...still not quite there yet.  Trying to figure out yet how to control the upload with a button so that the user has a choice to upload or not.  I still need to parse through the SDK some more.

Comment: Yep - as I said, it's the start of an answer, but not the full code; the SDK is relatively simple when you get to know it, but there are a few dependencies and issues to understand first.